# On comparing two different notions of compactly generated space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, soft-question, category-theory, compactness

I have encountered, in different circumstances, the following two slightly different categories:

> The full category of $\mathsf{Top}$ consisting of all objects that are:
>
> a) topological spaces such that all compact subspaces are closed and that any subset is closed iff its preimage of every embedding of a compact subspace is closed (denotes by $\mathsf A$);
>
> or
>
> b) topological spaces such that all images of Hausdorff compact spaces are closed and that any subset is closed iff its preimage of every continuous map from a Hausdorff compact space is closed (denotes by $\mathsf B$).

I find that $\mathsf B$ is contained in $\mathsf A$, but I have no idea if $\mathsf B$ is properly contained in $\mathsf A$. Does anyone know  the answer?

Besides, if $\mathsf A$ and $\mathsf B$ are distinct. I'm also wondering what's the advantages and disadvantages of using  $\mathsf A$ instead of $\mathsf B$, and conversely?

Comment: Why did you remove your example?

Comment: @BenjaminGadoua Because it's wrong…

Comment: Please, if you found the answer yourself, do not edit your question! Instead post an answer. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question. You just won't get rep points for accepting your own answer.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi OK I've added an answer.

Comment: You wrote that for any Hausdorff non compactly generated space $X$, the one point compactification of $X$ yields a counterexample. I think this does not work either. There are countable Hausdorff non compactly generated spaces, and if $X$ is such a space, then it is not sequential. But the one-point-compactification of a countable space is $KC$ only if that space is sequential (see https://www.emis.de/journals/CMUC/ps/cmuc0204/Alaswil.ps).

Comment: So far I have no idea whether the implication 4 in your answer is true or not...

Comment: @StefanHamcke Yes, you are right. So another critical mistake. Thanks for your careful examination.